# ? being generated as %3f in rewritten url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have an htaccess file which is rewriting a single get parameter in my url, which is a string

```
# Rewrite for instagram_gallery.php?DataSource=1
RewriteRule ^instagram-gallery/([_./:a-zA-Z0-9#%@\(\)\[\]\-\,\']+)/?$ instagram_gallery.php?DataSource=$1 [NC,L]
```

i have tested the htaccess using https://htaccess.mwl.be/

the url parses ok, but it converts, (for instance)

```
www.sitename.com/instagram-gallery/parametervalue
```

to

```
www.sitename.com/instagram_gallery.php%3FDataSource=parametervalue
```

replacing the ? with %3F

this results in a 404 not found, but if I replace the %3F in the output string, it works

Comment: replace this [NC,L] by [NE,NC,L] and test again

Comment: thanks, that ALMOST works. - only issue i now have is when the string parameter itself contains a question mark, the url is truncated